# how to create a mobile version of your cakePHP site?

Tags: responsive-design, mobile-website, mobilize.js

I have a website created in Cake PHP . How do I create a mobile version for it ? Do I need to create a new layout/theme or can I just alter CSS a bit to resize the pages?

Comment: Search Google for "responsive web design" This has *nothing* do to with CakePHP and is *pure* client side HTML / CSS work.

Comment: yes i understand , but I dont even have a html file on my server , its only CSS and JS along with theme and layout . how do I go about this creating a mobile version without HTML ?